# When i use set_index,I am not able to create a seperate dataframe with set_index column name

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to extract values in "d" row for the next 7 days  from todays date(say 2020-04-22).So I have transposed the df so that dates will be in a seperate column.I want a seperate dataframe with Account and d column  to calculate 7 days from todays date (apr 22) using account column.I am beginner to dataframes and numpy and I am learning concepts.

I know i should use date.today() but I am not able to access account column since I used it as set_index

```
  cashflow_path = "./data/input/wpptest.xlsx"
    pd_xls_obj = pd.ExcelFile(cashflow_path)
    data= pd.read_excel(pd_xls_obj,sheet_name="Sheet1")
    data
```

[image]

I have transposed the sheet so that I can easily calculate from todays date

```
inp=data.set_index('Account').T
inp
```

[image]

```
inp=inp[['Account','d']]
inp
```

Key error:Account not in index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set 'Account' to be the index you can't select it as a column, but you only need to select the column 'd' and the dates will appear as well. To make 'Account' a column, just duplicate it from the index.

```
inp['account'] = inp.index
inp = inp[['account', 'd']]
```

Comment: Can you please let me know if there is any documentation related to duplicating the index.Is it similar to .copy()?I just want to know in detail of how inp.index works.I have just started learining dataframes and sorry if my question seems baseless.

Comment: Not a problem - everyone needs to start somewhere! Here is a good place to get started: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html

Comment: As far as I know, when you take any slice of a dataframe, it's completely unrelated to the original. The same goes for copy, so no need to use it in this context. .copy() might be useful if you are setting one dataframe the same as another, but want to keep the original one as well and not have any changes affect the new dataframe.